# Is this algorithm for counting inversions in an array O(n) complex?

Tags: algorithm

I came across a solution in `Python` for the problem [Count inversions in the array](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/), which uses "non-comparative sorting algorithm to get the count". It makes 2 recursive calls to a code which executes bitwise operations.

```
def inv_count(a, m=(1 << 32)):
    if not m or not a:
        return 0
    count = 0
    ones, zeros = [], []
    for n in a:
        if n & m:
            ones.append(n & ~m)
        else:
            count += len(ones)
            zeros.append(n & ~m)
    m /= 2
    return count + inv_count(ones, m) + inv_count(zeros, m)


print inv_count([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print inv_count([2, 4, 1, 3, 5])
print inv_count([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

Is this solution truly linear `O(n)`?

Similar SO question claims it's not possible ([Is there an algorithm to count array inversions in linear time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999945/is-there-an-algorithm-to-count-array-inversions-in-linear-time)), and while there is lot of literature on *divide-and-conquer* algorithms (with `O(n logn)` complexity), I would thank for some reference regarding the solution above.

Comment: Can this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array - there are some `O(n log n)` solutions, which I think indicates that is the minimum you can go...

Comment: the algorithm you posted is not linear `O(n)` since it is recursive calling `inv_count(ones, m)`. It is `O( n * log n )` .

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I made a simple timeit script in `Python` which showed that a classic `divide-and-conquer` solution is way faster (2-3 times) than this code with bitwise operations... : https://gist.github.com/oskar-j/f9bb24e4c390cedd3216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's O(n w), where the maximum number is less than 2^w. If w = 32, as the code assumes, then yes, this is a linear-time algorithm. On the other hand, there is an O(n log d)-time comparison-based algorithm for inputs with at most d distinct elements, which is also linear when d = 2^w = 2^32. The Ω(n log n)-time lower bound applies to comparison-based algorithms where all input elements may be distinct.

Comment: What's the name of this alleged n log d sort? :)

Comment: @NiklasB. I have no idea about names. I think of it as a counting sort analog that augments a BST-based map on ≤d keys to do prefix sums on the values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's linear for numbers which are limited by value (32bit).

It's similar with counting sort ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort ) for sorting.